# How to use CKEditor as form input?

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to make simple web editor using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) but i cant find out how to make it work.

First i checked their samples site. Only thing they do to make CKEditor work is include .js file and add ckeditor class to form textarea element.

```
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
.
.
.
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
```

So i copy .js file and try it in my own folder and when i run php script whole textarea element is hidden and doesnt create CKEditor panel as it should like in [this sample page.](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/13-09-03-13-05/full/samples/replacebyclass.html) There might be some javascript configuration but i havent found any in source code of sample page.

Comment: Open your browser debugger. See any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Copy all of your `ckeditor` folder to server.
2. Add it to html page ;like this:

   ```
   <script src="../script/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
3. Assign CSS class of `ckeditor` to `textarea`; like `class="ckeditor"`.

Answer (score 10):

call `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );` in your js files or simply in your html file like this:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
      <form name="ckeditor">
         <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
</form>
```

As given in the main website.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name=msg id="editor">Text</textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
        .then(editor => { console.log(editor); })
        .catch(error => { console.error(error); });
</script>
```